# Multi-group SEM analysis - regression paths

Tags: r, structural-equation-modeling, lavaan

I am using SEM to model the intergenerational social class mobility with education as a mediator for father class. However, I also have a latent variable - ability - which is then also having a direct path to education and the outcome variable (class of destination). 
I would like to perform a multi-group analysis between 3 cohorts and to simplify the things compare them in pairs.

However, I have some doubts on the proceedings. I know that with CFA and latent variables the steps are those to test the measurement invariance i.e. configural model vs weak invariance, vs. strong invariance etc. But what if I have regression paths? I mean, I've found some examples  using only regressions-paths, comparing the free model with a constrained where regressions and intercepts are equal across groups and then testing which paths should be free or not.

In my specific case, I realized that the ANOVA test for constrained and free model is significant only if I constrained the intercepts, otherwise the two models are not significantly different. What does it mean? Shall I constrain the intercepts and then identify the paths that needs to be free?

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 1):

The point of testing invariance is to make sure that your latent variable represents the same thing in each group that you test. If one group interprets a question differently, invariance won't hold, and this tells you not to use the latent variable. (E.g. I have found that British students and American students interpret the word 'touchy' differently - to an American, touchy means 'sensitive', to a Brit, touchy means 'tactile'). I

If you have regression paths and you are running multiple group models, presumably it's the regression paths you are interested in? So constraining and testing these tests the null hypothesis that the paths are equal across groups.

Comment: Yes, exactly. I am interested in regression paths. But when making the comparison I was including the group.equal=c("regressions", "intercepts"). I then realized that what makes the free and constrained model to be different are exactly only the intercepts. Can I conclude the Multigroup is not necessary, right?

Comment: I don't think you've given enough information for me to say that.  Are you using the functions to assess invariance? I think you might need to code these models 'manually', not use the automatic tools. The automatic tools are not designed for your situation. (I'm not sure, I never use them, because I want to be sure what models I'm comparing.)

Comment: Indeed I've firstly used the "manual" comparison using the labels to coefficients to compare the free and constrained model. They resulting to be not statistically different, they are only when I constrain the intercepts in the latent part of the model. Therefore, I've checked for the invariance in the latent part of the model, but it fails to reach the strong invariance, neither the partial one.

Comment: Which intercepts? The latent intercepts, or the measured intercepts?

Comment: The latent intercepts, which seems to me coherent with the fact I have only weak invariance in the latent part of the model

Comment: I think it's confusing to talk about things like weak invariance in the latent part of the model. Talk about what you're testing, and which parameters.

Comment: That's the issue that confounds me: how to properly test the multi-group with a latent variable within regression paths. I've tested both manually (adding the label to coefficients) and with group.equal option the free vs the constrained model. I constrained firstly only the regression coefficients only and the 2 models are not significantly different. They are significantly different only if I allow to group.equal=c("regressions", "intercepts"). After some checks, I observe they are different only due to the intercepts of the latent variable.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/107163/discussion-between-jeremy-miles-and-luca-giangregorio).